# Create dynamic query from the Dataframe present in Spark Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, switch-statement

I have a dataframe DF as below. Based on the Issue column and Datatype column I wants to create a dynamic query.
If Issue column is **YES** then check for the Datatype, If its **StringType** add **Trim(DiffColumnName)** to the query or if Datatype is integer do some other operation like **round(COUNT,2)**
And for the column for which Issue type is **NO** do nothing and select the Column itself

Query should be like this

```
Select DEST_COUNTRY_NAME, trim(ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME),round(COUNT,2)
+-------------------+-----------+-----+
|     DiffColumnName|   Datatype|Issue|
+-------------------+-----------+-----+
|  DEST_COUNTRY_NAME| StringType|   NO|
|ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME| StringType|  YES|
|              COUNT|IntegerType|  YES|
+-------------------+-----------+-----+
```

I am not sure if I should be using If else condition here or case statement or create a UDF. Also my dataframe (i.e. columns) are dynamic and will be changed every time.

Need some suggestions how to proceed here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the following piece of code.

- Derive the new column by applying the required operations
- Use collect_list to aggregate the values to an array
- Format the output using concat_ws and concat

```
val origDF=Seq(("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME","StringType","NO"),
("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME","StringType","YES"),
("COUNT","IntegerType","YES"),
("TESTCOL","StringType","NO")
).toDF("DiffColumnName","Datatype","Issue")

val finalDF=origDF.withColumn("newCol",when(col("Issue")==="YES" && col("DataType")==="StringType",concat(lit("trim("),col("DiffColumnName"),lit(")")))
when(col("Issue")==="YES" && col("DataType")==="IntegerType",concat(lit("round("),col("DiffColumnName"),lit(",2)")))
when(col("Issue")==="NO",col("DiffColumnName"))
)

finalDF.agg(collect_list("newCol").alias("queryout")).select(concat(lit("select "),concat_ws(",",col("queryout")))).show(false)
```

I included an additional column to the data for testing and it is giving me the desired output.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|concat(select , concat_ws(,, queryout))                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|select DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,trim(ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME),round(COUNT,2),TESTCOL|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```